# USB device detected but can't view the files - I am using a VirtualBox with Host as Windows and Guest Os as Ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, usb, virtualbox

Host OS: Windows 7

Guest Os: Ubuntu mate 14.04 LTS.

VirtualBox : 4.3.28

a) I added the current user to the usersgroup 'vboxusers' and rebooted.

b) I added a usb filter in VirtualBox settings and added the usb device that is plugged in.

I am able to see the usb storage device with the command 'lsusb'. 
But I am not able to actually view the usb folder on the desktop of Ubuntu.

Rgds,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try mounting your USB device or even if the USB device's file system is NTFS it won't be detected in Ubuntu.